# What is this piece called? two connected cylinders

Tags: part-identification

[image: two connected cylinders]

Hi, I'm putting the pieces together for a Vostok spacecraft. I'm stuck at this piece, can anyone help me identify it please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That would be

Part# [30360 : Cylinder 3 x 6 x 2 2/3 Horizontal - Round Connections Between Interior Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30360#T=C)

or

Part# [93168 : Cylinder 3 x 6 x 2 2/3 Horizontal - Square Connections Between Interior Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=93168#T=C)

Both are essentially the same part, just a mold variation

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, absolute hero

Comment: I wonder why they changed this mold?  The old one seems *slightly* more useful in that it has those open studs that you could maybe stick something into.  Not a big deal as I don't see too many use cases for that, just curious.